# jQuery syntax for targeting div of class inside div of another class

Tags: jquery

Two jQuery questions:

1)  Given this HTML structure

```
<div id="tipper" class="tiplink"><a href='test.html' >Link Text</a>
<div id="tip" class="tipdiv">This is the tool tip text.</div>
</div>
```

How can I alter these to work on classes so that that when a div of class `.tiplink` is moused over the div of class `.tipdiv` inside it is targeted?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tipper').mouseover(function() {
      $('#tip').clearQueue().show(0);
    });

    $('#tipper').mouseleave(function() {
        setTimeout( function(){
        $('#tip').hide(0);
      },20000);
    });
```

2) Without using a text input is it possible to select all the text in `.tipdiv` on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.tiplink').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).find('div.tipdiv').clearQueue().show(0);
    });
```

and for the click

```
$('div.tiplink').click(function() {
     var text =  $(this).find('div.tipdiv').text();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  #1 solved.  I guess I did not phrase #2 well.  What I am hoping to select it in the same way JavaScript select(); works on a text input's content so user can right-click to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover()`. It's built for that.

```
$('#tipper').hover(function(){...on state..},function(){...off state...})



$('#tipper').click(function() {
  var myText = $('.tipdiv').html();
   alert(myText)
}
```